# Checking all columns for an unbound datagrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have the following datagrid:

[image]

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DataGridOrderItems" Margin="4,10,0,-16"
VerticalGridLinesBrush="LightGray"  HorizontalGridLinesBrush="LightGray" AlternatingRowBackground="Beige"  AlternationCount="2" 
SelectionMode="Single" SelectionUnit="FullRow" 
AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="False" SelectionChanged="dataGridOrderItems_SelectionChanged" FrozenColumnCount ="1">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Select" CellTemplate="{StaticResource Template}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Resource Id" Binding="{Binding ResourceId}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Resource Name" Binding="{Binding DisplayTitle}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Quantity" Binding="{Binding Quantity}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Type" Binding="{Binding ResourceType}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Order Date" Binding="{Binding OrderDate, StringFormat=\{0:d\}}" IsReadOnly="True" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Status" Binding="{Binding Status}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGrid.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu >
            <MenuItem Header="Select All" Click="SelectAllDatagridOrderItems"  />
        </ContextMenu>
    </DataGrid.ContextMenu>
</DataGrid>


<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="Template">
        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

Unfortunately the grid isn't databound and I'm trying to create a menu item to select all items in the grid (***to set the value of the first column to checked for everything not just select the rows themselves***).

I'm a bit perplexed how to  go about it. I've tried to bind it to a context and then reset that to the itemsource with little success. What would be the best way to approach this?

Comment: I added new solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made similar feature recently. The best way is to create a behaviour:

1. Add check box above the grid (select all)
2. `SelectionMode` property should be "**Extended**"
3. Create behaviour
4. Bind check box and datagrid to this behaviour:

   public class Behaviour
   {

   ```
   public static bool? GetSelectAll(DependencyObject obj)
   {
       return (bool?)obj.GetValue(SelectAllProperty);
   }

   public static void SetSelectAll(DependencyObject obj, bool? value)
   {
       obj.SetValue(SelectAllProperty, value);
   }

   // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for SelectAll.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
     public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectAllProperty =
       DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("SelectAll", typeof(bool?), typeof(Behaviour), new PropertyMetadata(null,
           (o, e) =>
           {

               DataGrid dg = o as DataGrid;
               if (dg != null)
               {
                   bool selctAll = Convert.ToBoolean(e.NewValue);
                   if (selctAll)
                   {
                       dg.SelectAll();
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       dg.UnselectAll();
                   }
               }

           }));
   ```

   }

And XAML:

```
<StackPanel>
    <CheckBox x:Name="CheckBox"></CheckBox>
    <DataGrid local:Behaviour.SelectAll="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=CheckBox}"></DataGrid>
</StackPanel>
```

I hope it helped.
I've run this solution and it works fine.

Comment: Great in theory, but the same problem I had initially - SelectAll() won't work with this property.

Comment: Sounds strange. I've done it before more than once and I have never stuck on SelectAll().
What is your items source?
Could you give me the full code? I will run it later to detect the problem.
First of all remove all not vital properties setting to determine what property make a problem. Have you removed   SelectionMode from Single to Extended?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using DataGridTemplateColumn, you can use `RowHeaderTemplate`  for the CheckBox. Then bind the CheckBox's IsChecked property to DataGridRow's IsSelected property. That way, whenever a row is selected, the checkbox would be checked, and vice versa.

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DataGridOrderItems" PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="dataGridOrderItems_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" SelectionMode="Extended" SelectionUnit="FullRow" ...>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Resource Id" Binding="{Binding ResourceId}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Resource Name" Binding="{Binding DisplayTitle}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Quantity" Binding="{Binding Quantity}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Type" Binding="{Binding ResourceType}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Order Date" Binding="{Binding OrderDate, StringFormat=\{0:d\}}" IsReadOnly="True" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Status" Binding="{Binding Status}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGrid.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu >
            <MenuItem Header="Select All" Click="SelectAllDatagridOrderItems"  />
        </ContextMenu>
    </DataGrid.ContextMenu>

    <DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}}}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
</DataGrid>
```

Thus selecting all rows in the DataGrid would also check all the checkboxes:

```
private void SelectAllDatagridOrderItems(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridOrderItems.SelectAll();
}
```

Also, in order to select multiple rows, `SelectionMode` should be `Extended`.

One way to make it easier for user to select multiple rows, is to handle the DataGrid's `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` event. Then, use `VisualTreeHelper` to find the DataGridRow and select/unselect it.

```
private void dataGridOrderItems_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    DependencyObject depObj = (DependencyObject)e.OriginalSource;

    while (depObj != null && !(depObj is DataGridRow))
    {
        depObj = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(depObj);
    }

    if (depObj != null && depObj is DataGridRow)
    {
        DataGridRow dgRow = (DataGridRow)depObj;
        dgRow.IsSelected = !dgRow.IsSelected;
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

With this, user can select multiple rows without holding Ctrl. And the CheckBox checking system still works.

Comment: Although this will work it's far less user friendly (user is forced to hold control to select multiple rows).

Comment: I have included a way to let user select multiple rows without holding Ctrl. Perhaps it can be useful.

Answer (score 0):

OK. I think the penny drops at last!

I chanhed the XAML but behaviour still the same.
New XAML:

```
<DataGrid local:Behaviour.SelectAll="False"
              AutoGenerateColumns="False"
              x:Name="DataGrid"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
              HorizontalGridLinesBrush="LightGray"
              AlternatingRowBackground="Beige"
              AlternationCount="2"
              SelectionMode="Extended"
              SelectionUnit="FullRow">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Select">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <CheckBox  IsChecked="{Binding Path=(local:Behaviour.SelectAll),RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Item"
                                Binding="{Binding Item}"
                                IsReadOnly="True" />
         
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

[image]
[image]

I believe that it should be exactly what you need.